# select value in dropdown from database

Tags: php, html

I have four values in select, and in the database there may be only two values that are stored from them.

```
<select id="notebboktype" name="notebooktype">
    <option value="Convertible 2 in 1">Convertible 2 in 1</option>
    <option value="Notebook">Notebook</option>
    <option value="Laptop">Laptop</option>
    <option value="Ultrabook">Ultrabook</option>
</select>
```

How can I get selected value. I tried this:

```html
<option value="Convertible 2 in 1" <?php if ($row['notebooktype'] == "Convertible 2 in 1") echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>Convertible 2 in 1</option>
<option value="Notebook" <?php if ($row['notebooktype'] == 'Notebook') echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>Notebook</option>
<option value="Ultrabook" <?php if ($row['notebooktype'] == 'Ultrabook') echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>Ultrabook</option>
<option value="laptop" <?php if ($row['notebooktype'] == 'laptop') echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>laptop</option>
```

But it still gives me only first value selected.

Comment: Improved grammar and formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

> `multiple` attribute in your `<select id="notebboktype" name="notebooktype"` **multiple**`>`

And no need to echo **selected="selected"** just echo **selected**

```
<select id="notebboktype" name="notebooktype" multiple>
    <option value="Convertible 2 in 1">Convertible 2 in 1</option>
    <option value="Notebook">Notebook</option>
    <option value="Laptop">Laptop</option>
    <option value="Ultrabook">Ultrabook</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="notebboktype" name="notebooktype" multiple>
    <option value="Convertible 2 in 1">Convertible 2 in 1</option>
    <option value="Notebook">Notebook</option>
    <option value="Laptop">Laptop</option>
    <option value="Ultrabook">Ultrabook</option>
</select>


<select id="notebboktype" name="notebooktype" multiple>
    <option value="Convertible 2 in 1" <?php if ($row['notebooktype'] == "Convertible 2 in 1") echo 'selected'; ?>>Convertible 2 in 1</option>
    <option value="Notebook" <?php if ($row['notebooktype'] == 'Notebook') echo 'selected'; ?>>Notebook</option>
    <option value="Ultrabook" <?php if ($row['notebooktype'] == 'Ultrabook') echo 'selected'; ?>>Ultrabook</option>
    <option value="laptop" <?php if ($row['notebooktype'] == 'laptop') echo 'selected'; ?>>laptop</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is..

```
 <option value="Convertible 2 in 1" <?php if ($row['notebooktype'] == "Convertible 2 in 1") {  echo ' selected = "selected"'; } ?> >Convertible 2 in 1</option>
        <option value="Notebook" <?php if ($row['notebooktype'] == 'Notebook') { echo ' selected = "selected"'; } ?> >Notebook</option>
        <option value="Ultrabook" <?php if ($row['notebooktype'] == 'Ultrabook') { echo ' selected = "selected"'; } ?> >Ultrabook</option>
        <option value="laptop" <?php if ($row['notebooktype'] == 'laptop') { echo ' selected = "selected"'; } ?> >laptop</option>
```